# How do I distribute a (open-source) Vala project?

Tags: c, open-source, vala

One of the only languages that compiles to a high level language such as C, Vala has interested me for quite a bit. I've been wanting to start a small project with it, but I've been wondering how I would distribute it.

The fact is, that it compiles to C code (C99 I suppose).

- Can I distribute the C code instead
  of the Vala code?
- If I do, is the C code compatible with all platforms?
- Or does it, for example when using sockets, include the appropriate stuff (winsock.h for Windows) automatically?

Comment: "a high level language such as C"?!

Comment: @Roger: C is pretty high level compared to say, Assembly. But this has nothing to do with my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a Vala developer in irc, #vala on irc.gnome.org:

```
   18:57 < flo> It is of course possible to distribute the C code as
         well. The compiler itself is shiped with vala and C code. We
         actually access C-libraries over an abstract interface with all
         advantages and disadvantages of the libraries we are using,
         including platform dependencies.
```

Comment: Ooops, we posted simultaneously. Since I am not a vala programmer, I defer to Lucas, of course (+1). But why not ask the Vala people directly in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

Automake, as of version 1.10 or 1.11 has [Vala support](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/automake/Vala-Support.html).

Answer (score -3):

Did you google? did you try it out?   Does the Valal home page have anything to say? Did you ask on Vala forums? There are only 7 questions tagged Vala on SO (and one of those is "will Vala survive?"), so this might not be the best place to ask.

Why not just compile your vala to C and then run it through a C  compiler, preferably on a different PC (for a thorough test, make that 2nd PC one which has never one any development work and install a C compiler specially for your test).

Of course that might prove something for ***a*** program, but not for **all** programs. Perhaps ask the mailing list (http://mail.gnome.org/mailman/listinfo/vala-list), or the devlopers? Jürg Billeter - j at bitron dot ch  Raffaele Sandrini - rasa at gmx dot ch

The question, paraphrased, is "how long is a piece of string", the best answer is "suck it, and see", and the caveat is YMMV ;-)g